# Row counts by date range using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

We use Postgresql as our database engine.  I have a log table which maintains a log by timestamp of activity to various soap endpoints.  I need to produce a status screen which total failures and total messages sent over each endpoint.

I have created SQL which produces the desired results.  I need to turn this into HSQL and struggling.  I have two different date ranges and 2 different counts to produce from each date range.

I have been investigating this and it appears that I need to have multiple projections, one for each count as well as multiple criteria detailing the date range for that count.  All the examples I have found involve one count with it's associated criteria and projections.  What's the solution for this?

Here is my SQL

```
select ep.url, count(case when result = 'FAILED' AND activity_date = DATE(NOW()) AND activity_date > timestamp '2017-01-16 11:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) as failed_last_hour, 
   count(case when result = 'COMPLETED' AND activity_date = DATE(NOW()) AND activity_date > timestamp '2017-01-16 11:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) as completed_last_hour,
   count(case when result = 'FAILED' AND activity_date = DATE(NOW()) AND activity_date > timestamp '2017-01-16 00:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) as failed_today, 
   count(case when result = 'COMPLETED' AND activity_date = DATE(NOW()) AND activity_date > timestamp '2017-01-16 00:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) as completed_today
   from endpoint_log log 
left join routing_endpoint ep ON log.endpoint_id = ep.id
group by ep.url
order by ep.url;
```

It calculates the prospective dates in the SQL, however I expect to calculate the correct dates and provide those as params to the query.

I also plan to use a Transform so I can have it return objects with the results.

I appreciate any help you can be on this.  I find Hibernate relatively easy to work with but have never attempted to use Projections.  I assume I can just implement the SQL as written but I would like to at least attempt to use Hibernate the way it is intended before giving up.